# Need to Remove and Replace a Hook that is in Concrete

Tags: concrete, brick, masonry

I have a metal hook that has been put into hole in a brick wall using concrete.  I am wanting to remove it as a piece of the hook snapped off.  What is the easiest way to remove this hook and replace? Or am I better off contracting this project out? Who would you typically hire to do this kind of work? What would it run?  I do have access to a decent amount of power tools and have attached a picture for reference. [image]

Comment: 1 - Looks more like the hook is embedded in the mortar between bricks rather than in concrete, but hard to tell. 2 - My guess is that if the exact position is not critical then it would be better to whack off the rest of the hook and install a new one a few inches away. 3 - How much weight/tension on this hook? That will determine whether this should be "drill a hole, install an anchor and screw in a hook" vs. "drill a hole just the right size and screw in a hook", what type of anchor (if any), etc.

Comment: Correct - it is in the mortar between the bricks.  My fault for misstating.  The hook is used to lock up both bikes and an external storage container.  No constant tension will be on the hook nor do I ever expect to have a given load hanging off it at any point in time. I plan on using a eye hook of similar gauge.

Comment: I would not whack it off; this might damage the brick. First try to twist it loose with a pipe wrench or locking pliers (vise-grips). If that doesn't loosen it, I would cut it off with a hacksaw or a saws-all or a Dremel with a cutoff emery wheel.

Comment: have you tried to unscrew it? ... that hook end looks intact, what snapped off?

Answer (score 1):

If it were really concrete, an expansion eye bolt is an obvious choice: [image: Expansion Eye Bolt] Where you drill a hole, clean it out (without breathing the dust), and tighten.

But you've got brick which is crumbly, and you want it secure against theft and pull out.  Thus you should consider drilling a slightly larger hole, cleaning out yet better, and setting a new bolt with epoxy.

Or get a bolt with plate, and multiple tapcon type brick anchor screws to spread the load out a bit in the brick:
[image]

The old bolt will likely pull out with a pry bar or screwdriver with a twist.  You may be shocked how easy it comes out of mortar.

If you need to hire, hire a "handyperson" or "handy".

Answer (score 1):

Since the hook is embedded in mortar my recommendation is to do the following:

1. Using heavy duty pliers attempt to remove the hook or loosen it by twisting back and forth
2. If this fails, use a small stone chisel to carefully chip away the mortar around the hook.  If the hook comes out with the pliers you should still dig out the mortar a bit more around the opening.
3. Make a small batch of brick mortar (if you don't know what to buy, tell the local hardware store you need to 'repoint' some bricks in a few places and just need the right mortar.
4. Using a bag with a nozzle (like a piping bag for baking, they make them for mortar as well but you can get by with a trash bag with a small hole cut out in the corner), inject the new mortar into the hole.  Be sure to work the mortar in fully and get out any air pockets.
5. Insert the replacement hook in the wet mortar
6. Allow to cure fully and enjoy your fixed hook

Comment: It's not as cheap, but an [anchoring epoxy](https://www.quikrete.com/productlines/fastsetanchoringepoxy.asp) is probably going to be stronger than brick mortar and comes ready-to-use. The application would be done the same way.